# Trying to save the recordset results into array vba

Tags: vba

```
Sub TEST()

Dim str(5)

    Set cnn = New ADODB.Connection
    Set rs = New ADODB.Recordset

If cnn.State = adStateOpen Then cnn.Close
    cnn.ConnectionString = "Driver={Microsoft Excel Driver (*.xls, *.xlsx, *.xlsm, *.xlsb)};DBQ=" & _
    ActiveWorkbook.Path & Application.PathSeparator & ActiveWorkbook.Name
    cnn.Open

If rs.State = adStateOpen Then rs.Close
    rs.CursorLocation = adUseClient

strSQL = "SELECT DISTINCT ProductSubcategoryKey FROM [INSERT$] ORDER BY ProductSubcategoryKey DESC"

    rs.Open strSQL, cnn, adOpenKeyset, adLockOptimistic

'results are
'45
'40
'30
'34
'32

str(0) = rs(0)
str(1) = rs(1) 'Error occurs here
str(1) = rs(2)
str(2) = rs(3)
str(3) = rs(4)

Debug.Print str(0)
Debug.Print str(1)
Debug.Print str(2)
Debug.Print str(3)
Debug.Print str(4)

End Sub
```

the above code successfully returns the data into record set but when try to save into array it throws error.. can any one tell what's went wrong ?

Thanks for your time !!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error is because you have only selected 1 column. So your recordset includes only 1 column. You have to select 5 columns as per your code.

For your code to work you have to select 5 columns in your query. Otherwise if you just add 1 more column then it will fail on line below `str(1) = rs(2)`

If you want to print all records from recordset to str array then you have to loop through recordset. Also i would suggest to not have fixed size array. So change in your code from `Dim str(5)` to `Dim str()`

Now loop on recordset

```
For i = 1 to rs.RecordCount
   str(i) = rs(0)
next
```

Comment: Actually what i'm trying to achieve is ..to get the 5 distinct values from ProductSubcategoryKey column .. can u assist me in this ?

Comment: bue this wont work as its just 1 column being feteched. do you want to assign those values to str array?

Comment: Then you should loop in record set? do you know how to do it?

Comment: first tell me why you have array for 5 like str(5)? what happens if your query returns more than 5 records? In your case if query returns more than 5 records then you will print only 5 records in the str array

Comment: str(0),str(1),str(2),str(3),str(4) contains = 45 ..i look like str(0)=45,str(1)=40,str(2)=35,str(3)=32,str(4)=30

Comment: so you mean you get same values in array str? can you check what you get value of rs(0) inside the loop? please debug and let me know

Comment: @user3114645 you get value 45 for rs(0) inside loop 5 times?